# FPT algorithm for edge dominating set

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, parameterized-complexity

I have been attempting to learn parameterized complexity on my own, and decided to go through all of the FPT race problems, and defining easy FPT algorithms for them, using concepts such as bounded search tree. I am stuck on figuring out an FPT algorithm for edge dominating set, defined as follows:

**EdgeDominatingSet**

Instance: A graph $G=(V,E)$; a positive integer $k$.

Question: Is there a subset $D\subseteq E$ with $|D|\leq k$ such that for each $e\in E$, either $e\in D$ or $e$ shares an endpoint with an $e'\in D$.

Parameter: $k$

I'm not looking to define anything fancy, just a simple FPT result. Any help would be great!

Comment: I tried to see if any combinatorial techniques I could think of would work, or bounded search tree algorithms, but I cannot find anything to bound by the parameter k

Comment: What's an "FPT race problem"?

Comment: http://fpt.wikidot.com/fpt-races

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there are any really simple solutions. One algorithm is due to [Fernau](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~fernau/papers/Fer06b.pdf), and uses an enumeration of all vertex covers of size $2k$; within each of these, a simple dynamic programming algorithm attempts to find a small edge dominating set. Another (earlier) approach, due to [Prieto](http://vladestivill-castro.net/techreports/ElenaPrieto.pdf), uses kernelization.

Comment: Thank you! I was just looking for something a bit simpler, but yeah the parameter k doesn't give you much to work with